# Unable to click on autosuggest option webdriver selenium python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

This is the element I want to select "service-instance called 86... --Schema" as seen in the UI snapshot (link below), and no luck yet. Looking for suggestions. Thanks.

I tried both click() and send_keys.

**With click(), the erorr is as follows:**

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("react-autosuggest__input")
elem.send_keys("86e13df6-ba3a-4d5e-818c-fcf1b4e8160d")
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("react-autosuggest__suggestions-container") 
elem1.click()
```

> *selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view*

**With send_keys, the error is as follows:**

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("react-autosuggest__input")
elem.send_keys("86e13df6-ba3a-4d5e-818c-fcf1b4e8160d")
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("react-autosuggest__suggestions- 
container")
elem1.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
elem1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

> *selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard*

[Please refer to the GUI element I am trying to click on via selenium, also HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V45QN.png)

Comment: Have you tried inserting some wait time before clicking/sending keys?

Comment: Yes , that dint help either. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "reach-autowhatever-1")))
elem1.click()
```

OR

```
elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "react-autosuggest__suggestions-container")))
elem1.click()
```